# Adding quotes(single or double) to the json string

Tags: jackson

I have a string in json format but the string does not have quotes.

[{field1:value1,field2:value2}].

Now I have to convert this string into a ArrayNode using Jackson API. Because the string does not contain any quotes, it is throwing error that it is expecting double quotes. Also, I have already tried

```
 mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

but it is throwing error for values are not inside quotes.

Comment: This is expected. You ask Jackson to allow unquoted field _names_, this does not tell anything about values at all. Why don't you just produce valid JSON instead? Consider what would happen with `field1: true`, is `true` to be interpreted as JSON boolean true or a string with contents `true`?

Answer (score 0):

You should add @JsonRawValue annotation to the fields which you want to take into consideration for parsing, so it will quotes that fields accordingly.